# "No value given for one or more required parameters" error

Tags: vb.net, ms-access-2010

I'm writing an application and I'm getting this error:

> No value given for one or more required parameters

Code:

```
DA = New OleDbDataAdapter("select  TBL_BARANG as [Kode],Nama_BARANG as [Nama],Harga_Beli as [Harga Beli],Harga_Jual as [Harga Jual],Jumlah_BARANG as [Stok],Satuan_BARANG as [Satuan] From TBL_BARANG", CONN)
DS = New DataSet
DA.Fill(DS, "TBL_BARANG")
DGV.DataSource = DS.Tables("TBL_BARANG")
DGV.ReadOnly = True
```

Comment: Is `TBL_BARANG` a column or a table? Maybe remove it from the `SELECT` statement if it's the table you want to select from.

Answer (score 0):

AS stated by @Bugs the code for this query should be something like this:

```
DA = New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT Nama_BARANG as [Nama], Harga_Beli as [Harga Beli], Harga_Jual as [Harga Jual], Jumlah_BARANG as [Stok], Satuan_BARANG as [Satuan] From TBL_BARANG", CONN)
DS = New DataSet
DA.Fill(DS, "TBL_BARANG")
DGV.DataSource = DS.Tables("TBL_BARANG")
DGV.ReadOnly = True
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the alias from the query like below...

> select  TBL_BARANG ,Nama_BARANG ,Harga_Beli ,Harga_Jual ,Jumlah_BARANG
>   ,Satuan_BARANG  From TBL_BARANG